# order of route declarations in laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have made a laravel package which contains a route, it is a special route that catches a large number of possible urls. I don't want my route to take precedence over other packages or routes declared in the main application. How can I ensure that my route is the last route declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Routes are evaluated in the order that they are listed in routes.php. Simply making sure this route is the last one in the array should do it.

**update**

I believe you could just register the route in the App::before filter, which would register it after all user routes.

Comment: im talking about routes in my package though. I understand within my own route file that is true but what about all the other packages loading routes.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question on first read. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No, the before filter runs those routes before other named routes, I want after all routes (no names, or unknown names).

Comment: ahh, sorry you didnt mean a route before filter but an application before filter. So you're saying you register a route there?

Comment: Yes. I haven't tried it, but I believe if you do `Route::get()` in a `App::before(function(){})` the route defined there will be evaluated after all the routes in `routes.php` have been loaded because routes.php is loaded before the `App::before` filter is evaluated.