# Routing order in Laravel matters

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Does the order of routings matters in Laravel?

I have created the following routes:

```
Route::get('authors/new', array('as'=>'new_author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@getNew'));
Route::get('authors/{id}', array('as'=>'author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@getView'));
```

In the author controller, I have these:

```
public function getView($id)
{
    return View::make('authors.view')
        ->with('title', 'Author View Page')
        ->with('author', Author::find($id));
}

public function getNew()
{
    return View::make('authors.new')
        ->with('title', 'Add New Author');
}
```

When I go on the page `localhost/authors/new` , It works fine.

However, If I change the order of the routes like this:

```
Route::get('authors/{id}', array('as'=>'author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@getView'));
Route::get('authors/new', array('as'=>'new_author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@getNew'));
```

It doesn't work anymore, It says:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\views\authors\view.blade.php)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [order of route declarations in laravel package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870899/order-of-route-declarations-in-laravel-package)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870899/order-of-route-declarations-in-laravel-package

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old and probably stale, but I do not think that the possible duplicates mentioned in the comments fit to this question.

However, I found the following solution to this problem, which I have also just encountered.

Add the following constraint to your route so that it looks like this:

```php
Route::get('authors/{id}', array('as'=>'author', 'uses'=>'AuthorsController@getView'))
->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Like this, *Laravel* will check first if the parameter `id` is a number.

For more information, please [see the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).