# Create a Dynamic URL and Redirect to it in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

So basically this is what I need. I have a router definition like this.

```
Route::get('view/{postId}', 'PostController@view');
```

Above router definition will get triggered if the url we request is `www.domain.com/view/4`. But what I want is I want to appear this url like `www.domain.com/[category-of-post]/[titile-of-post]` (Ex : `www.domain.com/music/easy-chords-in-guitar`).

In `PostController`, I will get the post using the id passed and thus can generate the url what I need. Here is the problem begins. As you can see, I need to redirect to a dynamic url which will look differently for each post. **I want to redirect to this dynamic urls but these urls are not defined inside `routes.php`**.

Is this possible in Laravel ?

In short, what I need is, I want to update `Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::$route` array with my dynamically generated url value with corresponding controller action  in run time before I am invoking `Redirect::to('someurl')`

If you need further clarification, I will do it for sure. Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you just add the route:
`Route::get('view/{category}/{title}', 'PostController@viewByTitle');` and handle the new cases accordingly?

Comment: @FaKeller : I dont want `view` term in my route. I just want `{category}/{title}` but it is too broad url. Means `page/about`, `question/something`, `answer/anoher` and so on so on urls will satisfy that route rule and I cant go on with that.

Comment: If that is your problem, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20870914/1262901) may be helpful for you.

Comment: @FaKeller you commented first and it is the right answer. But itachi provided an answer first. I cant accept your comment as an answer. What should I do here ? Can I accept itachis answer ?

Comment: Yes, not a problem, go ahead ;-)

Comment: @FaKeller : that was a good decision. Laravel community is awesome. Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is simpler than you are thinking.

```
Route::get('{category}/{title}',['uses' => 'FooController@bar']);
```

**This should be the last route defined in your route list. Any other route should go upper than this one.**

this will match `www.domain.com/music/easy-chords-in-guitar`

rest routes define as you want.

e.g.

```
Route::get('/',['uses' => 'FooController@home']);
Route::get('about',['uses' => 'FooController@about']);
Route::get('contact',['uses' => 'FooController@contact']);

Route::get('{category}/{title}',['uses' => 'FooController@bar']);
```

Comment: uff. Got your idea. But @FaKeller redirected me to the right direction first through his comment ! Let me get a feedback from him and then will accept your answer. For now +1 for this answer :-)

Comment: Thanks. Accepting your answer based on Fakeller's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

route :

```
    Route::get('action/{slug}', 'HomeController@actionredeemvoucher')->name('home.actionredeemvoucher');
```

Function in controller:

```
    public function actionredeemvoucher($slug)
    {    
       print_r($slug);  
    }
```