# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

Previously I had trouble with [route precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997210/route-precedence-order)
with helps and suggestions I overcame it by adding regex in my route. Now my route is this:

```
Route::get('/{country}/{category}', ['as' => 'tour.list', 'uses' => 'LinkController@tourlist'])
            ->where('country', '[A-Za-z]+')->where('category', '[A-Za-z]+');

Route::get('/{category}/{slug}',['as' => 'single.tour', 'uses' => 'LinkController@singleTour'])
            ->where('category', '[A-Za-z]+')->where('category', '[w\d\-\_]+');
```

with this route I get error an error of:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

When I remove regex from first route I'm getting same problem as before and when I remove regex from 2nd route I get an error of:

```
Trying to get property of non-object 
(View: F:\project\resources\views\public\tours\show.blade.php)
```

My methods in LinkController are:

```
public function tourlist($country, $category){
$tour = Tour::whereHas('category', function($q) use($category) {
            $q->where('name','=', $category);
        })
        ->whereHas('country', function($r) use($country) {
            $r->where('name','=', $country);
        })
        ->get();
    return view('public.tours.list')->withTours($tour);
}

public function singleTour($slug,$category)
{
$tour = Tour::where('slug','=', $slug)
              ->whereHas('category', function($r) use($category) {
            $r->where('name','=', $category);
        })
        ->first();
   return view('public.tours.show')->withTour($tour);
}
```

And my code in view is:

```
<a href="{{ route('single.tour',['category' => $tour->category->name, 'slug' => $tour->slug]) }}">{{$tour->title}}</a>
```

Comment: Could you give us an example url of each route? So like `example.com/england/outdoor`?

Comment: @scottevans93 url of 1st route: `http://localhost:8000/Croatia/Cycling` url of 2nd route: `http://localhost:8000/Cycling/beach-side-cycling`

Comment: Both these urls produce the same HTTP Error?

Comment: Only 2nd route gives the error. First route is ok

Comment: Should `where('category', '[w\d\-\_]+');` no be `where('slug', '[w\d\-\_]+');`?

Comment: If the above is true, you Regex is slightly wrong

Comment: `[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+` should capture the slugs

Comment: Changed my route to: `Route::get('/{category}/{slug}',['as' => 'single.tour', 'uses' => 'LinkController@singleTour'])
    ->where('category', '[A-Za-z]+')->where('slug', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+');` as per your suggestion. Now the error is `Trying to get property of non-object `

Comment: Try `var_dump($tour);` just before the view is returned in the `singleTour()` method and post the result. It now sounds like your Model is not returning any data

Comment: The result is `NULL`. Is this because I have used category first in the route and slug first in the method ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130000/discussion-between-scottevans93-and-zachary-dale).

Answer (score 0):

**Change you Regex**

`where('category', '[w\d\-\_]+');` to `where('slug', '[A-Za-z\d\-\_]+');`

The above would solve the initial problem of the route not working properly.