# How pass Dynamic variable from url in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to fetch the data from database and display it view .
This is my  web.php

```
Route::get('/businesscard/{name}',  function ($name) {
    
    
//$username= App\users::where('username', $name);


$username=DB::table('users')->select('*')
                     ->where('username', '=', $name)
                    // ->groupBy('status')
                     ->get();
   
    return view('auth.pro')->with(['username' => $username]);
   
   
   
     return array(
       'name' => $name
       );
       
       
       
});
```

If the user enters domain.com/businesscard/username I need to  fetch the data for the username and display it in view .It is working.But I need to remove businesscard .User need to enter domain.com/username. I have tried the below code.

```
Route::get('/{name}',  function ($name) {
    
    
//$username= App\users::where('username', $name);


$username=DB::table('users')->select('*')
                     ->where('username', '=', $name)
                    // ->groupBy('status')
                     ->get();
   
    return view('auth.pro')->with(['username' => $username]);
   
   
   
     return array(
       'name' => $name
       );
       
       
       
});
```

If there is data it is working .but other pages are not working like login and register .Users  are entering their username in registration .

Comment: **`/{name}`** That means, **/login**, **/register** wont work.

Comment: check my answer it will helpful for you. If it's helpful then give a upvote and accept my answer.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your route matters. See [order of route declarations in laravel package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870899/order-of-route-declarations-in-laravel-package)

So the /{name} should be registered as the last route to avoid matching for other routes.

Comment: Thanks .I have changed the route order . It is working .

Comment: Please also mark it as the answer for others to find it.

Answer (score 0):

`/{name}` it means `/` with any value. If you try `/login` or `/register`.Then your logic is confused with this so that other pages are not working. Best way to develop as you expect like first one.

Another thing in your code there is two `return` second one is not doing anything. After the first one it return to view so second one unused. remove that `return` as well.