# Match RegEx just as given

Tags: php, regex

I have to routes in my MVC Framework:

```
$routes["\/"] = $index;
$routes["\/user\/(\d+)"] = $user;
```

With

```
$request_url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

I get the given URL.

And with

```
$reg_ex = "/$route/i";
$matches = [];

preg_match($reg_ex, $request_url, $matches);
```

I match all occurrences within this $request_url.

For example:
If I have the URL "/MVC-Framework/user/1" it matches only the "/" route, but not the correct "user" route.

The whole code:

```
$request_url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

echo $request_url . "<br />";

$index = function(){
    echo "index route";
};

$user = function(){
    echo "user route";
};

$http_404 = function(){
    echo "error 404";
};

$routes = [];

$routes["\/"] = $index;
$routes["\/user\/(\d+)"] = $user;

foreach($routes as $route => $action){
    //$reg_ex = "/" . $route . "/";
    $reg_ex = "/$route/i";
    $matches = [];

    preg_match($reg_ex, $request_url, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

    if(!preg_match($reg_ex, $request_url, $matches)){
        continue;
    }

    if(!is_callable($action)){
        return call_user_func_array($http_404, $matches);
    }

    array_shift($matches);

    return call_user_func_array($action, $matches);
}

return call_user_func_array($http_404, [$request_url]);_array($http_404, [$request_url]);
```

The output is:

> /MVC-Framework/user/42

> Array ( [0] => / ) index route

Comment: Ultimately, order matters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20870914/2943403 (This is typically true when checking routing patterns in any framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two routes but the URL you are testing will match the regular expressions for *both* routes. That is, "/MVC-Framework/user/1" can be matched by both `/\//` and `/\/user\/(\d+)/` and you are testing the regular expressions in the order in which they are defined. Any URL that matches `/\/user\/(\d+)` must also match `/\//`. **If you have a route regular expression that matches a subset of all the strings that a second route regular expression matches, then you must test that regular expression first.** In your case the strings matched by `/\/user\/(\d+)` is a subset of the strings matched by `/\//` and so must be tested first.

So simply reverse this order:

```PHP
<?php
...
$routes["\/user\/(\d+)"] = $user;
$routes["\/"] = $index;
...
```

But I suspect that the actual regular expression you want for the $index function is `/^\/$/`, so that the matching URL must be *exactly* "/". In this case no regular expression matches a subset of the other and the order in which you test will not alter the results.

Comment: Did this answer your question to your satisfaction?

Comment: Excuse my late answer, I think yes. I could not try it yet, but I think your answer will help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I will do then. Thank you. :)